# Нужно чтобы при нажатии на элемент в зависимости от условий он загорался либо красным либо зелёным на несколько секунд. JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на элемент в зависимости от условий он загорался либо красным либо зелёным на несколько секунд. Помогите реализовать это на JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Lesson 5. The Restaurant | EngHome</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="EngIcon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"><div class="header col-sm-12"><h1>Lesson 5. The restaurant</h1></div></div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="riddle colored color sizewrdqs"><p class="word">Spoon</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <ul class="answers">
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Вилка </li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Тарелка </li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Сковорода</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Ложка</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Рыба</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Кофе</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Лобстер</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Чай</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Бублик</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Чашка</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">СуперМегаУльтраЛирикРыба</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton">Стакан</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="examples">
        <p> Examples: <br> 1. My spoon good stuck when i tried to stir it. <br> 2. Lee, i'm not satisfied until the spoon. </p>
    </div>
    <a href="https://t.me/Haltteon" target="_blank" id="author"> By <span style="color: #28b5b5;"> @Haltteon </span></a>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.riddle {
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 15px; 
    font-size: 28px;
    border-radius: 18px;
}

.colored {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0090f7d1, #cff112e8);
}

.licolored {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #0090f7d1, #cff112e8);
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 520;
}

.libutton:hover {
    border: 4px solid #51c4d3;
}

.libutton:active {
    border: 4px solid #29bb89;
}

.examples {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-left: 54px;
}

#author {
    position: absolute;
    right: 26px;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: black;
    font-family: "Сomic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 480;
}

.option {
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: ivory;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
    -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
    -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */   -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                        not supported by any browser */
}

.sizewrdqs {
    font-size: 32px;
}

.answers {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.color {
    color: white;
}

.header {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
/*    body {
        color: red;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .col-sm {
        color: green;
        background-color: green;
    }*/
}
```

Вот что я попытался сделать:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Lesson 5. The Restaurant | EngHome</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="EngIcon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    funcion TrueVariant() {
      document.getElementById("Элемент, который вызвал эту функцию").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }

    function FalseVariant() {
      document.getElementById("Элемент, который вызвал эту функцию").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    </script>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"><div class="header col-sm-12"><h1>Lesson 5. The restaurant</h1></div></div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="riddle colored color sizewrdqs"><p class="word">Spoon</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <ul class="answers">
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Вилка </li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Тарелка </li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Сковорода</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="TrueVariant()">Ложка</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Рыба</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Кофе</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Лобстер</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Чай</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Бублик</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Чашка</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">СуперМегаУльтраЛирикРыба</li>
                    <li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant()">Стакан</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="examples">
        <p> Examples: <br> 1. My spoon good stuck when i tried to stir it. <br> 2. Lee, i'm not satisfied until the spoon. </p>
    </div>
    <a href="https://t.me/Haltteon" target="_blank" id="author"> By <span style="color: #28b5b5;"> @Haltteon </span></a>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Так вот я не могу понять - как сделать так, чтобы в JS коде в document.getElementById определялось какой элемент вызвал функцию.

Заранее большое спасибо!)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример того, что вы попробовали на JS и что у вас там не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function TrueVariant(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

function FalseVariant(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="FalseVariant(this)">Сковорода</li>
<li class="option colored licolored libutton" onclick="TrueVariant(this)">Ложка</li>
```

Comment: Нет, не заработало.

Comment: @JustRizer_ заработало

Comment: Извини. Всё работает, спасибо :)

Comment: @JustRizer_ Пожалуйста. Успехов!